# Month swaps to Day, Day swaps to Month when loading View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, culture

So I got this controller which is like this:

```
public ActionResult Create(int teller, DateTime datum, int AfdelingId, int WerknemerId, int KwartaalId)
{
    DienstGepland dg = new DienstGepland();
    dg.datum = datum.AddDays(teller);
    dg.gecontroleerd = false;
    dg.WerknemerId = WerknemerId;
    dg.DienstKwartaalGeplandId = KwartaalId;

    ViewBag.afdelingid = AfdelingId;
    ViewBag.diensten = _service.DienstenList(AfdelingId);

    return View(dg);
}
```

`dg.datum` is filled in like for example: "13/03/2012".

But when it open the Create View the date in the EditorFor is changed to: "03/13/2012".

View:

```
@model ProjectMivalti.Domain.DienstGepland
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.datum)
```

This may not happen of course. I think it is a culture problem but i have no idea how to fix it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try formatting it like this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DateModified, new {value = Model.DateModified.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")
```

Comment: being german, he would go for the model.datum.ToString("dd/MM/yyy") format, but except that, that's the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you're setting appropriate `CultureInfo` on current `Thread`, preferably in Global.asax BeginRequest.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
}
```

Comment: I hoped this would help, but in my case this did not change the behavior.
I had to explicitly define the format when returning the model to the controller:

    `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ProcessingDateTimeStart, new { name = "ProcessingDateTimeStart", Value = Model.ProcessingDateTimeStart})`